# Matlab: Referring to dataset column with a variable containing the column name

Tags: matlab, variables, reference, dataset

I have a dataset with couple of columns with pre-defined names. I would like to access a column in this dataset by using a variable, which contains the column name in char-type. How should I do the referencing?

I've tried:

```
dataset.variableName
```

which doesn't work.

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parentheses for [dynamic field names](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html):

```
 dataset.(variableName)
```